# Threads: unable to open database file with sqlite3 inside docker

Tags: python, multithreading, docker

I am using a Flask application run by gunicorn which works fine if I run it directly on my server but fails if I run it inside Docker with the error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/app-root/src/backend.py", line 242, in runAlertManager
    db = get_db()
  File "/opt/app-root/src/backend.py", line 29, in get_db
    db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

If I get a cli inside the docker container I can use the sqlite3 client just fine on that file. If I remove the Threading part it also works fine just not sure why it does work directly but not in Docker

Simplified I have something like this

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from flask import g, Flask, request, jsonify, current_app
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        print(DATABASE)
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

def runAlertManager(app):
    '''
    Runs AlertManager in a separate process
    '''
    with app:
        db = get_db()
        while True:
          #do something
          sleep(10)

x = Thread(target=runAlertManager, args=(app.app_context(), ))
x.start()
```

Comment: Well, what is `DATABASE`? Is it a path to a file that is accessible within the Docker container?

Comment: just the path pointing to /db/database.db which is mounted into the container and exists.

Comment: You might find it more straightforward to connect a Docker-based application to an RDBMS running in a separate container (like PostgreSQL or MariaDB); this helps get around issues around file permissions, and it will help you if you decide you want to scale the application up to multiple running copies of the container.

Answer (score 0):

> just the path pointing to /db/database.db which is mounted into the container and exists.

The entire directory an SQLite database exists in needs to be writable; SQLite needs to create some sidecar files (e.g. for `database.db`, `database.db-wal` or `database.db-journal`).

Instead of mounting just the file, mount the directory it's in.

Comment: That is done that way and the folder is writable